# How to display both of total order sale price and regular price (or total discount price) in cart page in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a question. I want to show/display the sum of both order sale price and regular price (or total discount price) in cart page in woocommerce. I would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Do you know how to modify WooCommerce PHP templates? Do you know which template to modify? Have you tried anything? Typically here you are required to at least try, and then post what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. The answer is in the link below

[Display Total Discount Amount / Total Savings](http://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-display-total-discount-savings-cart/)